# Xcode 5.1 - No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=i386)

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5.1

After updating to Xcode 5.1, I can no longer build my project for the 64-bit simulator, receiving this error:

```
 No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=i386).
```

These are my target build settings:

[image: Xcode target build settings]

I tried changing "Build Active Architecture" to No, as well as adding "i386" to the "Valid Architectures", unfortunately neither worked.
Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: I've seen quite a few similar questions in the wake of the latest iOS 7.1 update and the solution was to leave out arm64. Admittedly, that doesn't solve your specific problem but there is reason to believe Apple messed something up.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, I guess I won't use 64-bit until Apple releases an update for this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [EXC\_BAD\_ACCESS, code 1, iOS 7.0.x 64bit devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22332410/exc-bad-access-code-1-ios-7-0-x-64bit-devices)

Comment: Same issue on Xcode 6.1, have tried all solutions given below, they are not working. I have CocoaPods in my project. Any solution on how to fix it on Xcode 6.1

Answer (score 102, accepted):

I had the same error message after upgrading to XCode 5.1.  Are you using CocoaPods?  If so, this should fix the problem:

1. Delete the "Pods" project from the workspace in the left pane of Xcode and close Xcode.
2. Run "pod install" from the command line to recreate the "Pods" project.
3. Re-open Xcode and make sure "Build Active Architecture Only" is set to "No" in the build settings of both the "Pods" project and your own project.
4. Clean and build.

Comment: Fixed by removing arm64 from Pods architectures.

Comment: Solved the same problem in a Cordova/PhoneGap project for me too. Thanks

Answer (score 184):

What you need to do is just set the `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH` to `NO` (at least works for me). Below is a screenshot for it:

[image]

---

#### EDIT:

As far as I know (*please point it out if there's something wrong, thanks*), if you set `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH` to `YES`, it means the Xcode will only build for the active architecture (which refers to the device that's active in Xcode currently). Seems Xcode's default setting is set Debug to `YES`, so it won't build binaries for other architectures when you only want to build for a special device that connected to your Mac.

The reason failed to build might be that, the project does not support the architecture of the device you connected. **So the best solution is to add the right architecture for your device.** Below is a list for architectures & the devices that support:

- ARMv8/ARM64: `iPhone 6`, `iPhone 5s`, `iPad Air`, `Retina iPad Mini`
- ARMv7s: `iPhone 5`, `iPhone 5c`, `iPad 4`
- ARMv7: `iPhone 3GS`, `iPhone 4`, `iPhone 4S`, `iPod 3G/4G/5G`, `iPad`, `iPad 2`, `iPad 3`, `iPad Mini`
- ARMv6: `iPhone`, `iPhone 3G`, `iPod 1G/2G`

So why *"set the `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH` to `NO`"* works? Because the device can still run the binary that built for all architectures you added (pass the build), but will lose some performance. This's just a quick solution, but not best.

---

**Note**: The more architectures you added, the bigger the binary will be generated. So it's good to choose right architectures for your project. ;)

Comment: @EmilMarashliev just the build target. You'll see it when you select your root project (with blue icon).

Comment: @Praveen not sure, seems this option get changed in Xcode 5.1.

Comment: this was very helpful. the answer would be complete, if you can add how to download the architecture that is needed.

Answer (score 29):

Add `arm64` to the target's `valid architectures`. Looks like it adds `x86-64` architecture to simulator valid architectures as well.

Answer (score 27):

If you are using CocoaPods, the most likely problem is because your Pods project Build Settings for **Build Active Architecture Only** is set to **Yes** for Debug.

The solution is simple. Change it to **No**.

Similarly, change to **No** for your application project.

Answer (score 12):

I had similar issue. Got it solved by changing **"Architecture"** to "**$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)**" in Build Settings for Project.

Now, you have to select **Standard architectures (armv7, arm64) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD)** since apple recommends apps to be build on 64-bit architecture. Click : [Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12172014b)

Comment: @JayprakashDubey, what about this? `$(ARCHS_STANDARD_INCLUDING_64_BIT)` ?

Comment: Should I use `$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)` or `$(ARCHS_STANDARD_INCLUDING_64_BIT)` ?

Comment: @hagile :  Go with $(ARCHS_STANDARD_INCLUDING_64_BIT)

Answer (score 10):

Add:
Architectures: $(ARCHS_STANDARD_INCLUDING_64_BIT)

Valid architectures: arm64 armv7 armv7s

Comment: Hmm, did you trie to reset everything, simulator content, simulator, clean project, restart xCode and Mac, cause I have xCode5.1 and my simulator is working well

Comment: Are you running your app/simulator using iPhone 4-inch 64-bit?

Answer (score 5):

Just in case, for anyone still encountering the issue despite following the above, check that the simulator you are running is also the supported one. I had mine specified to arm7 and arm7s but was trying to run the app on a 64 bit simulator.

Comment: +1 Yes, this is the one! After checking and re-checking and triple-checking that everything is still ok, this was the problem!

Comment: Wow. I have to actually plug in the device I want to build for in order to get the proper target code compiled? I just puked a bit in my mouth. Your post solved this issue for me, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

To avoid having "pod install" reset only_active_arch for debug each time it's run, you can add the following to your pod file

```
# Append to your Podfile
post_install do |installer_representation|
    installer_representation.project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'NO'
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add arm64 in valid architecture.i hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 3):

My problem was that the Pods project was targeting OS X, despite my Podfile having `platform :ios`. I'm using cocoapods 0.35.0.rc2.

To fix it, select the Pods project in the project navigator, and check that the Pods PROJECT node (mind you, not the Pods target) is targeting iOS. That is, the architectures build settings should be:

- Architectures: `$(ARCHS_STANDARD)`
- Base SDK: `iOS 8.1`
- Supported Platforms: `iOS`
- Valid architectures: `$(ARCHS_STANDARD)`

I also wanted to build all architectures, so I added the following to the Podfile:

```
post_install do | installer |
    installer.project.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH'] = 'NO'
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I had to add the following `i386` and `x86_64` to `Valid Architectures`. I'm running Xcode 7.2 and targeting iOS 8+. I already had `armv7`, `armv7s` and `arm64` in there and that was working in Xcode 6.4.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem when running my app on iPad using xcode 5.1. It got resolved by removing armv7s from 'valid architectures' and setting the 'build active architectures only' value to No. Both these fields can be found in your app->targets->build settings->architectures.

Answer (score 2):

I arrived at this question due to a problem with command line build for simulator in Xcode 7.2. In case anyone else gets here with the same issue, I will share the solution I found:

Apparently there is [a bug in Xcode 7.2](https://openradar.appspot.com/23857648) that causes `xcodebuild` to fail when trying to build for simulator. The solution is to specify the option "-destination", e.g:

```
xcodebuild -project TestBuildCmd.xcodeproj -scheme TestBuildCmd -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 6' build
```

**Update**

The above example command will build a binary including the graphics for iPhone 6 only. If the binary is run on other simulators, the iPhone 6 graphics is scaled to the platform. A [better workaround](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/27975#109127) which contains all graphics for all platforms is to specify the parameter `PLATFORM_NAME=iphonesimulator`, for example:

```
xcodebuild -project TestBuildCmd.xcodeproj -scheme TestBuildCmd -sdk iphonesimulator -arch i386 PLATFORM_NAME=iphonesimulator build
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all previous architectures (i.e. remove the ARCHS_STANDARD setting) at the same time as you add i386 to the Architectures. This should change the active architecture to i386. I encountered a similar issue when I tried to build for armv7 by default, but it kept trying to build for arm64. I changed ARCHS_STANDARD to ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT, and this changed the active architecture chosen.

Answer (score 0):

In acrhiecture - sometimes to support 6.0 and 7.0 , we exlude arm64

In architectures - > acrchitecture - select standard architecture arm64 armv7 armv7s.
 Just below in Valid acrchitecture make user arm64 armv7 armv7s is included.
This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using @Kjuly's answer and the specific line:

*"The reason failed to build might be that, the project does not support the architecture of the device you connected."*

With Xcode loaded it automatically set my iPad app to iPad Air

[image]

This caused the dependancy analysis error.

Changing the device type immediately solved the issue:

[image]

I don't know why this works but this is a very quick answer which saved me a lot of fiddling around in the background and instantly got the app working to test. I would never have thought that this could be a thing and something so simple would fix it but in this case it did.

Answer (score 0):

I found that it was necessary to enter the architecture names by hand:

[image]

I don't know why this was necessary, i.e. why these values were not inherited from Xcode itself. But as soon as I did this, the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

In Valid architectures: Select each entry (release, debug) and build and press backspace. It should work