# Cocoapods error with XCode 5.1

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I updated Xcode to the 5.1 version and when I try to build my project I get the following error:

> Pods was rejected as an implicit dependency for 'libPods.a' because its architectures 'armv7s' didn't contain all required architectures 'armv7 armv7s'

Any solution? I've tried updating the cocoapods gem with no success.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This should fix the problem:

1.Delete the "Pods" project from the workspace in the left pane of Xcode and close Xcode.

2.Run "pod install" from the command line to recreate the "Pods" project.

3.Re-open Xcode and make sure "Build Active Architecture Only" is set to "No" in the build settings of both the "Pods" project and your own project.

4.Clean and build.

More on this topic:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22336208/1041311