# "library not found for -lPods-TARGET-j2objc-shared" error for j2objc-gradle plugin

Tags: j2objc

I have a simple shared project with a couple of Pojos

After running the gradle tasks:

```
./gradlew clean build j2objcXcode
```

and running pod install in my iOS app I get the below error when running the app in xcode:

```
ld: library not found for -lPods-iosApp-j2objc-shared
```

Am I missing a step here?

My machine details:

OSX 10.10.4
java version "1.8.0_40"
gradle 2.4
xcode 6.4
CocoaPods 0.34.2

Comment: Please let me know if this solved your issue. I'd appreciate the feedback.

Comment: Your original answer to delete the *.a file under Frameworks and then deleting the entries in the OTHER_LDFLAGS argument got me past my original error.

Now the plugin is complaining that it cannot find the guava library - see the updated gradle issue -> https://github.com/j2objc-contrib/j2objc-gradle/issues/273

Comment: I understand #273 was fixed by removing the slash? If this fix works without doing the workaround, please mark it correct so others can benefit in the future.

Comment: I will retest on a new project this evening and update this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must open the `MyProject.xcworkspace` instead of the `MyProject.xcodeproj` file.

This is a requirement when working with CocoaPods, which the j2objc-plugin uses to configure Xcode. See answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28111728/1509221. If you mistakenly open the `xcodeproj`, then it will be missing the required "Pods" project. This is a screenshot you should see when opening the `xcworkspace`:

[image]