# Can not build Develop branch for Xcode 7 project on El Capitan due to "linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, git, cocoapods

Xcode version: 7.0.1.
OS-X: Version 10.11 Release.
Project details: Built for iOS 7 or above, CocoaPods: AWSCore (Problematic one, other Pods build fine), other developers are on Xcode 7.0.1 as well but not on El Capitan.

When I try to build, I get "linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)", along with a few warnings linked to the error.
Warning 1: "ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/sonny/{PROJECT_NAME}/build/Debug-iphoneos'"
Warning 2: "ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/sonny/{PROJECT_NAME}/Pods/HockeySDK/Vendor'"
Warning 3: "ld: library not found for -lAWSCore"

**Solutions**

I've tried: I've tried a complete pod remove master repo, pod setup, pod install. I've tried verifying that the architecture settings are the same for build on both my project target and pods target. I've tried deleting entries on Testing->Debug && Release in Build Settings along with putting $(inherited) in all the linker files and framework search entries.

Other issues that might be related: In the Project Navigator, all of my Frameworks Podfiles are red, indicating an incorrect folder reference. But wouldn't pod install correct this? I simply can't find the pods.a files anywhere in my project folder but I do **not** know if this is what's causing the build to fail.

Project builds for all other developers but not me or my supervisor.  I'm on El Capitan but he isn't.

Comment: try this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23539147/xcode-ld-library-not-found-for-lpods

Comment: check your directory Debug-iphoneos and see if you have all the frameworks files exist in that folder

Comment: Looks like you have the problem when building the app on device. Check if it occurs when building on simulator

Comment: I tried all those @Max and it was still no go.

Comment: I've checked the directory Debug-iphoneos and only some of the frameworks files are there. AWSCore is not named libPods-AWSCore.a anymore, in the folder it was called libAWSCore.a. I manually clicked the folder to change the reference, still won't work.  
@Mr.T - I'm trying to build on simulator. Won't build on device or simulator.

Comment: if that is the case, delete all the frameworks on that folder and add required frameworks on your app target->general tab- > embedded binary frameworks

Comment: add your pod files and framework by clikcing on + sign

Comment: None of that fixed the issue.  
Here's the other weird thing. I built a new project that wasn't pulled from repo, used the same CocoaPods, did a pod install, opened the workspace and there are no frameworks folders in the project navigator.

Answer (score -1):

Solved:
This was my solution and keep in mind, the solution for everyone will be different -
In {Project Name} target, under your specific "General" if you scroll down you'll have a list of Frameworks. You want to delete ALL the Pod listings there "libPods-this or that.a". Those frameworks have been linked in a bash script and in other places during a Pod install, but Pod install didn't delete them from the project build listing.
Once you remove all those, it should build.

Comment: I did this and it failed even faster.