# ld: library not found for -lPods-ProjectName-AFNetworking

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocoapods

I have used `CocoaPod` in my project.

When i run `pod install` command and after that running my project i am getting an error as -

> ld: library not found for -lPods-ProjectName-AFNetworking
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Can anyone help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Do you open project or workspace?

Comment: please open  .xcworkspace file instead of the .xcodeproj file.

Comment: i have opened .xcworkspace file but still getting the error

Comment: please check this link its may be helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23539147/xcode-ld-library-not-found-for-lpods

Comment: @Pooja Srivastava your link is not worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Remove AFNetworking in podfile

Use this

target :App do

pod 'AFNetworking', '3.1.0'.

end

target :AppTests do
    …
end

Via terminal again Pod install

You can change AFNetworking version. Open Workspace of your Project not Xcode

Comment: my app working fine on iPhone 5 simulator but build failed when i change the simulator to iPhone 6.

Comment: yes my app is created 3 year ago. it is working fine before running podfile again

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I added pod for an existing workspace.

This what worked for me:
Go to YourProject -> Manage schemes -> tick on Pods