# Xcode build gives this error: ld: library not found for -lFMDB

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart, simulator

I am trying to run flutter on Xcode with simulator But I get this error:

> ld: library not found for -lFMDB

Answer (score 1):

Please update all your current pubsec.yaml packages/dependencies that your project uses.  Especially anything that uses Firebase or Facebook.  If that doesn't work open your project in XCode and add the relevant libraries like so...

[image: Linked Frameworks and Libraries Example]

Comment: thanks.the problem was that I should have opened xcode from Runner.xcworkspace

Comment: Thanks @geekymano, more info here https://stackoverflow.com/a/28111728/348589