# ld: library not found for -lDoubleConversion clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

ld: library not found for -lDoubleConversion

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

How to solve this issue ?

Comment: did you find solution for this error?

Answer (score 1):

add the below to your pod file and then run `cd ios && pod install`

```
pod 'DoubleConversion', :podspec => '../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec'
```

Comment: have you tried this. - https://stackoverflow.com/a/28111728/7022711