# Xcode - Library not found for -lDoubleConversion

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I get these errors when I try to build an iOS application.

ld: library not found for -lDoubleConversion
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

How to solve this issue ?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63666297/1971013

Comment: Hi thanks for response , I have tried this but still same.

Comment: You need to check if the CocoaPod generates the `DoubleConversion` in library version, so a `libDoubleConversion.a` or something file.  If so make sure that Xcode is able to find this library file using the `-L<some-path>` compiler/linker options.