# ld: library not found for -lcrypto MacOS

Tags: c++, macos, openssl

While trying to install this software:http://graphics.berkeley.edu/resources/ARCSim/
I'm running through the following error when running the makefile in the /dependencies folder.

```
ld: library not found for -lcrypto
```

I'm on MacOS BigSur.

Thanks in advance for the help !

Comment: Does this article answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23539147/xcode-ld-library-not-found-for-lpods

Comment: libcrypto is supplied by OpenSSL. Do you have OpenSSL headers and libraries installed and the paths set up in the ARCSim build? It should hopefully have found it itself if it's based on GNU autoconf or cmake.

Comment: Hey
I installed directly from source without using homebrew and it fixed the problem

Answer (score 2):

You’ll need to carefully read the installation instructions and install all dependencies — in particular, for your error message, OpenSSL, e.g. [via Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/openssl@1.1).

Comment: Hey, THanks it did fix the problem.
I installed directly from source without using homebrew