# No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=i386, VALID_ARCHS=arm64 armv7 armv7s)

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild, xcode5.1

**Preface:** I did look at [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22328882/xcode-5-1-no-architectures-to-compile-for-only-active-arch-yes-active-arch-x)s and none of the answers seemed to fix my problem.

I am trying to build my xcode (version 5.1.1) project using:

`xcodebuild clean build -sdk iphonesimulator7.0 -arch "armv7s" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO`,

when I run this I get: `No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=armv7s, VALID_ARCHS=i386 x86_64)` as an error. I tried the above command with all of the VALID_ARCHS (rm64 armv7 armv7s) as inputs. So I then tried running this command:

`xcodebuild clean build -sdk iphonesimulator7.0 -arch "i386" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO`

and I then get `No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=i386, VALID_ARCHS=arm64 armv7 armv7s)` as an error. I tried running the above command with all the other VALID_ARCHS (i386 x86_64) and no luck with that either. I don't know why these architecture errors are occurring. I have cocoapods in my project, and the first answer in the link above didn't fix my issue.

Comment: [By default, Xcodebuild builds the first target listed in the project (and with the default build configuration)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xcodebuild.1.html). How many targets are in your project?  does the first

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I have "arm64 armv7 armv7s" under `Valid Architectures` in my xcode project

Comment: add "i386" too, since the Simulator is using a different architecture.

Comment: So it should be `... -arch "i386 arm64 armv7 armv7s"`?

Comment: `Valid Architectures` should *include* "`i386`".

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Pls help me always getting No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=i386, VALID_ARCHS=arm64 armv7 armv7s) error

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can override your default variables:
Try to use this:

```
xcodebuild clean build -sdk iphonesimulator7.0 -arch "i386" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO VALID_ARCHS="i386 x86_64"
```

If you building for Simulator - always build for i386/x86_64.

Comment: How do you fix this inside the Project Settings?

Comment: in my case i add this line by reference of above answer -arch i386 ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO VALID_ARCHS=i386 its work for me .thanks @Sath89

Answer (score 3):

Go to your project settings (not targets). Then open Build Settings and add a value to **Valid architectures**: i386