# Issue No architectures to compile in iPhone Old project to new Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I Developed project with Xcode 4.6 Now i Run this project in Xcode 5.1 I got the following error.

```
No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=armv7 armvx86_64 armv7s).
Warning: Multiple build commands for output file /Users/mac3/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloPic-hjrlxpefxytgvshdfdalpvwpcjoa/Build/Products/Debug/HelloPic.app/Contents/Resources/audio-icon1.png
Warning: Multiple build commands for output file /Users/mac3/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloPic-hjrlxpefxytgvshdfdalpvwpcjoa/Build/Products/Debug/HelloPic.app/Contents/Resources/audio-icon1@2x.png
```

Please help me any one. I can't run this project in New xcode. i am very beginner to iOS.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 5.1 - No architectures to compile for (ONLY\_ACTIVE\_ARCH=YES, active arch=x86\_64, VALID\_ARCHS=i386)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22328882/xcode-5-1-no-architectures-to-compile-for-only-active-arch-yes-active-arch-x)

Comment: Hello @Neeku Its not Dublicate. My issue is very differnt to you metioned link. how you told its dublicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Target Under **Build Settings -> Architectures -> Base SDK** to **Latest iOS(version number)**.

check the below Image

[image]

I hope It will work for you.