# compile error for iphone 6 (No architectures to compile)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios8, iphone-6

I am trying to run app on iPhone 6, but i get this error mentioned below, i have shifted xcode 5 to version 6.0.1, i tried every solution but no success. My app runs successfully on iPhone 5 and iPhone 4s but it always give me error on iPhone 6. Is this `iOS 8` issue? I am new to `iOS 8`. Please help me how to solve it? Why i am getting this error?

```
No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=i386)
```

Thanks

Comment: watch this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22328882/xcode-5-1-no-architectures-to-compile-for-only-active-arch-yes-active-arch-x

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved for me just by following these steps 
go to

```
Targets> build Settings> Build Active Architectures set to NO
```

Comment: I had to make sure to do this on my pods also

Answer (score 3):

You could try to change the Build Settings property Build Active Architecture Only to No.

[image]