# what does adding arm64 to do?

Tags: ios, iphone

To get my app to run on the iPhone 6 plus simulator, I have to add the arm64 architecture into the valid architectures. I got the fix from this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22328882/xcode-5-1-no-architectures-to-compile-for-only-active-arch-yes-active-arch-x)

But, what does adding arm64 to the architecture do?

Pertaining to my app, it has been on the App Store without arm64. What happens when someone with iPhone 6 plus downloads my app on the App Store and tried to open it. Will it crash?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A 32-bit app can be opened on a 64-bit device, but doing so requires loading a second, 32-bit version of the system. So it's inefficient.

Comment: Good discussion in the tech talks (https://developer.apple.com/tech-talks/videos/) under "Architecting Modern iOS Games" - the talk is about 64-bit, it has nothing to do with games really.