# xcode 5 compile for arm64 iPhone failed

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, xcode, cmake

I am now building a C++ library for iPhone with xcode 5. When I build the architecture "armv7","armv7s" and "i386", everything is fine. But when I want to build for the architecture of "arm64", I have:

```
 C++ Compiler:                CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-NOTFOUND  (ver 5.1.0)
```

It seems that it cannot find the c++compiler. By the way, I am now using cmake toolchain to build the library, and more detailed error messages are as follows:

```
-- Setting up iPhoneOS toolchain
-- iPhoneOS toolchain loaded
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 5.1.0
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 5.1.0 
CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib;/usr/lib
-- Looking for linux/videodev.h
CMake Error at /Applications/CMake 2.8-11.app/Contents/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed

-- Looking for linux/videodev.h - not found
-- Looking for linux/videodev2.h
CMake Error at /Applications/CMake 2.8-11.app/Contents/share/cmake-2.8/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you setting the target architectures? If you specify them in CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS, try using CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES instead.

Any reason to not use Xcode 6 and CMake 3+?

Comment: I am using a python script to do the trick: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/platforms What I did is to go to the ios directory and then run python build_framework.py ios

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22328882/xcode-5-1-no-architectures-to-compile-for-only-active-arch-yes-active-arch-x I found the similar problem.

Comment: It is not exactly the answer, but for the time being I have not found any solution yet.