# ipa size different while project are same

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa, xcode6.1

I have 2 different named projects. Both have same file same size only difference in icons and splash screen and project name.

App folder size is same. But when I am creating ipa for both then there is huge difference (>4MB) in ipa size. Can any one help to figure this out?

Comment: For the 2 different projects, do you add target specific files? Those would contribute only to 1 target.

Comment: No. I am not adding target specific

Comment: Then how are you creating 2 different IPAs? I thought you must have one project and 2 targets.

Comment: I have 2 different named project. Both have same file same size only difference in icons and splash screen and project name.

Comment: Add this detail to the question as well please

Comment: You can extract the .ipa files content and check the difference yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you created your projects in different time, thus have different settings. You can go to

> Xcode > Target > Build Settings > VALID_ARCHS

check whether they're the same (something like `arm64`, `armv7` & `arm7s`). The more you offered in `VALID_ARCHS`, a bigger ipa will be got after you archived.

---

Further reading for `VALID_ARCHS`, you can check [THIS ONE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22328882/xcode-5-1-no-architectures-to-compile-for-only-active-arch-yes-active-arch-x/22394605#22394605).

Comment: This is the issue. I have not added arm64 in second one so I am getting the lesser size of ipa file. thanks

Comment: @MayankPurwar cool! B.t.w., u'd better to add `arm64` for ur 2nd project as well, for this reason: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=10202014a