# ios 7 Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 on ios 7

Tags: ios, ios7, armv7

I am working on xcode 6 and I create a static library, the application working fine on ios 8 but I got this problem Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 when I try to lunch the app on ios 7.

Can someone tell me why please?

Comment: It's probably because you're trying to run on a iPhone 4 or 5 that are armv7 (it does not depends on the iOS version).
To run on those devices, your static library has to be compiled for both architecture.

Comment: Clean project... delete derived data from organiser and try to build it again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Select project target > Build Settings > Search for "VALID_ARCHS"

Check whether you've added `armv7`, if not, add it.

---

Further reading about "VALID_ARCHS", you can refer to [THIS ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22328882/xcode-5-1-no-architectures-to-compile-for-only-active-arch-yes-active-arch-x/22394605#22394605).

Comment: @HoussamHammoud how about the static lib u created? make sure both project & lib support the arch of ur device.

Comment: same also I added it, I used the library for many other apps but I face the problem only for this app

Comment: @HoussamHammoud weird, what's ur device?

Comment: I have 2 device the iphone 5s (ios 8.2) the app work fine on it and iphone 4s (ios 7.1) here is the problem @kjuly

Comment: @HoussamHammoud weird, can u offer more detail about the error? there're lots possibilities available for this type error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7

Comment: Finally, it worked I only delete the Bolts.framework and the app now working fine.. I will accept your answer because you are trying helping me

Comment: @HoussamHammoud cool, thx. seems the framework does not support the arch. nice catch :D