# No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=x86_64, VALID_ARCHS=i386)?

Tags: ios

This is the error I am getting when compiling my project.

I have tried changing the architectures, still get the error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 5.1 - No architectures to compile for (ONLY\_ACTIVE\_ARCH=YES, active arch=x86\_64, VALID\_ARCHS=i386)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22328882/xcode-5-1-no-architectures-to-compile-for-only-active-arch-yes-active-arch-x)

Answer (score 2):

Go to build settings.

Search Build Active Architecture Only, and set that value YES