# Sinch SDK integration error : Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: objective-c, xcode7, sinch

I am getting below error in project with **`Sinch SDK`**

`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::find_last_of(char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long) const", referenced from`

**What I tried.**

- Change Architectures to `armv7, armv7s` as suggested [here](https://github.com/gt-liu/MiniChat).
- Remove arm64 from valid Architectures as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22328882/xcode-5-1-no-architectures-to-compile-for-only-active-arch-yes-active-arch-x).
- I compare build setting from Sinch sdk samples downloaded from [here](http://www.sinch.com/ios-sdk).

---

**What i am using**

- XCode 7.1.1 (Build project)

**Download** 
You can download my project from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7T692JXc2-gUnhWR3NNbzZFOUk/view?usp=sharing).

**Image**
[image]

How can I build my sample project? Would someone suggest some settings for it?

Comment: Remove x64 is not required anymore we do support that. are you using pods or doing it manually? If manually make sure you have all the required frameworks and that you set -ObjC -XLinker in other flags https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/ios/#firsttimesetup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove x64 is not required anymore we do support that. are you using pods or doing it manually? If manually make sure you have all the required frameworks and that you set -ObjC -XLinker in other flags https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/ios/#firsttimesetup or use cocapods