# Debugger won't deploy 32-bit app on 64-bit machine

Tags: ios, xcode, 64-bit, 32-bit

Is there a way to get XCode to allow me to debug 32 bit apps on 64 bit devices?

I have an old enterprise app, that uses libraries that only support 32 bit architectures. XCode only lets me debug on 32 bit devices.

If I try to run on a 64 bit device I get 
"No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=arm64, VALID_ARCHS=armv7)."

I think XCode thinks I want to build a 64 bit device since I plugged in a 64 bit device.

I know the app can run on 64 bit devices because I manually install IPA's of 32 bit apps onto 64 bit devices all the time.

Does any know of a setting in XCode that could help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 5.1 - No architectures to compile for (ONLY\_ACTIVE\_ARCH=YES, active arch=x86\_64, VALID\_ARCHS=i386)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22328882/xcode-5-1-no-architectures-to-compile-for-only-active-arch-yes-active-arch-x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH to NO and architectures $(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)