# Xcode 11 - Adding New Target For Apple Watch

Tags: apple-watch, xcode11

I have created a new Target for Apple Watch in new Xcode 11. But After creating it I am getting the following error. 
 **No architectures to compile for (ARCHS=i386, VALID_ARCHS=armv7s arm64 armv7).**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 5.1 - No architectures to compile for (ONLY\_ACTIVE\_ARCH=YES, active arch=x86\_64, VALID\_ARCHS=i386)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22328882/xcode-5-1-no-architectures-to-compile-for-only-active-arch-yes-active-arch-x)

Answer (score 0):

Solved :

I got mine to compile by resetting Valid Architectures in the watchkit extension to $(ARCHS_STANDARD) which converts to armv7k.  Seemed to work for me so far.